# compress image with JavaScript in React application

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, redux, base64

I have a react application and I want to compress images (base64) in client side and then send them to server. It works with following codes but in iphone it doesn't work.
I try to use image.onload but it still doesn't work

```
let compressedImages = [];
for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  let sourceImage = document.createElement('img');
  let result_image = document.createElement('img');
  imageCompressQuality = 50;
  sourceImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + images[i].PhotoPath;
  //PhotoPath is a base64 string
  result_image.src = compress(sourceImage, imageCompressQuality, 'jpg').src;
  compressedImages.push({
    PhotoId: images[i].PhotoId,
    PhotoPath: result_image.src.split(',').pop()
  });
}
```

and compress function:

```
compress (source_img_obj, quality, output_format) => {
  let mime_type = "image/jpeg";
  if (typeof output_format !== "undefined" && output_format == "png") {
    mime_type = "image/png";
  }
  let result_image_obj = new Image();
  let cvs = document.createElement('canvas');
  cvs.width = source_img_obj.naturalWidth;
  cvs.height = source_img_obj.naturalHeight;
  let ctx = cvs.getContext("2d").drawImage(source_img_obj, 0, 0);
  let newImageData = cvs.toDataURL(mime_type, quality / 100);
  result_image_obj.src = newImageData;
  return result_image_obj;
};
```

Comment: what do you mean by iphone? does not work on browser running in iphone?

Comment: @ReiDien Yes, it doesn't work on iphone browsers like safari and chrome